# Programmatically remove Firefox's license agreement dialog

Tags: firefox, unix, selenium, headless

I am running regression tests with [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) and am automatically launching instances of Firefox.

The problem is my tests get stuck because of Firefox's license agreement dialog:

[Copyright notice http://img151.imageshack.us/img151/3467/31963141.png](http://img151.imageshack.us/img151/3467/31963141.png).

I can't click with the mouse because I am in an headless environment with a virtual graphical environment.

I would like to know what Firefox's file can I edit (and how to edit it) to trick Firefox into thinking somebody accepted the copyright.

**Clarification following comments**

**I need to do it just once. But I can't do it with the mouse as this is a virtual graphic environment and I don't have mouse or see the mouse pointer. I can however take screenshots.**

Comment: I don't get it ... firefox shows this everytime it gets run or what?

Comment: no, it shows this just once. I need to fix it once. But I don't have mouse, and I can't see the screen. It is a virtual graphic environment. (I can take screenshots however)

Comment: Mozilla (tried) asserting its trademark via an EULA. The attempt failed, caused a major backlash in the FLOSS community and the idea was quickly abandoned. See my answer for a thread on the topic from Ubuntu.

Comment: Can someone just report this? The OP is trying to circumvent a legal agreement (that doesn't even exist any more). Please vote to close if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found it by myself in the end.

The right answer is:

In the Firefox installation, look for `firefox.js`

Find this line:

`pref("browser.EULA.3.accepted", false);`

and replace `false` whit `true`

Thanks to all that helped.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link text](http://www.desktoplinux.com/news/NS8123220578.html) its been removed - but it look like a later version than yours.

Answer (score 0):

Write a Selenium test that clicks "I agree"

or

add whatever "agreed" setting makes Firefox skip this to the Firefox profile's `prefs.js`

or

just use a Firefox profile that has already agreed to the license.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox 3.0.10 it's hidden in the `about:config` under

```
browser.rights.3.shown
```

Set it to `true` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

There are two override prefs (the latter being the "legacy EULA pref"), which you can override in prefs.js in the profile directory:

```
user_pref("browser.rights.override", true);
user_pref("browser.EULA.override", true);
```